# Different behavior with .val() and .attr("value") using ajax return data on a clone()'d but uninserted element

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, xhtml

As the title says, I'm trying to set the value of a `.clone()`'d form field using the results of a `$.getJSON()` request.  All of the return values have the same key as the name attribute of the form field they belong to.

Naturally, I tried to use `.val("foo")` to deal with cross-browser/field type discrepancies but it wouldn't work.  Oddly, `.attr("value","foo")` does.

Any ideas?  Is this expected behavior, or an undocumented quirk?  Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
function showSites(){
$.getJSON("process.php?action=showSites", function(data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data.sites, function(key, val) {  
        var $form = $("#addSiteForm").clone(); 
        var buttons = '<button id="getCert" class="button" href="getCert.php?id=' + val.id + '">Get Cert</button>'
            + '<button id="updateSite" class="button" href="process.php?action=updateSite&id=' + val.id + '">Update Site</button>'                                                                              
            + '<button id="deleteSite" class="button" href="process.php?action=deleteSite&id=' + val.id + '">Delete Site</button>';

        // set siteId
        $form.find("input[name=siteId]").attr("value",val.id);

        // change values
        $.each(val, function(i,v){
            $form.find("[name="+i+"]").val(v);
        });

        items.push('<h3><a href="#">' + val.name + '</a></h3>');
        items.push("<div class='site'>");
        items.push("<form class='siteForm' id='"+val.id+"'>");
        items.push($form.html());
        items.push("</form>");
        items.push(buttons);
        items.push("</div>");   
    });
    var foo = items.join('');
    $("#sites").prepend(foo).accordion("destroy").accordion();                  
});
});
```

Comment: A few things I've noticed: `clone()` + `val()` seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/mRXMm/ — the problem has to be elsewhere. / Don't duplicate ids. An `id` should be unique across the DOM. Use a class otherwise. / I don't believe `href` is a valid attribute for a `<button>` element. You should probably use a link here. / An id must not start with a number — `id='"+val.id+"'` looks like it might in your case. / Maybe that helps you to track down the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.val()` property in input tags( text box, textarea,..) only.

`attr("attrname","value")` this is used to set value to any tags. You can set some dummy attr in div tag and retrieve value `attr("attrname");`